# Count label distribution based on fold amount

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following data set:

```
df 

image_name target, folds
....jpg,     1,     0
....jpg,     1,     0
....jpg,     2,     2
....jpg,     3,     1
....jpg,     2,     2
```

Now, I want to find the `target` distribution for each fold. how to do it in python?

Comment: `df.groupby('folds')['target'].value_counts(normalize=True)`.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to `normalize`?

Comment: You can also use: `df.groupby(['target', 'folds']).size()`

Comment: It's up to you. Normalize gives you the distribution, i.e. percentage. Without it, you just have the counts.

Comment: One last thing, would you please inform how should I plot this information in a proper way (using `plt` or `seaborn`? I didn't ask this specifically but I would highly appreciate if you give. And would you please answer in the answer box? Sorry for bothering. :(